# Writing to txt file from StringWriter

Tags: java, file-io, stringwriter

I have a StringWriter variable, `sw`, which is populated by a FreeMarker template. Once I have populated the `sw`, how can I print it to a text file?

I have a for loop as follows:

```
for(2 times)
{
    template.process(data, sw);
    out.println(sw.toString());
}
```

Right now, I am just outputting to the screen only. How do I do this for a file? I imagine that with each loop, my `sw` will get changed, but I want the data from each loop appended together in the file.

**Edit:** 
I tried the code below. When it runs, it does show that the `file.txt` has been changed, but when it reloads, the file still has nothing in it.

```
sw.append("CheckText");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
out.println(sw.toString());
```

Comment: See my answer, it shows how to use PrintWriter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.txt");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
sw.write("some content...");
fw.write(sw.toString());
fw.close();
```

and also you could consider using an output stream which you can directly pass to `template.process(data, os);` instead of first writing to a StringWriter then to a file.

Look at the API-doc for the `template.process(...)` to find out if such a facility is available.

## Reply 2

`template.process(Object, Writer)` can also take a FileWriter object, witch is a subclass of Writer, as parameter, so you probably can do something like that:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.txt");    
for(2 times)
{
    template.process(data, fw);
}
fw.close();
```

Comment: It does work but my data gets overwritten every time the loop executes. How do i append data?

Comment: use the other constructor of file writer `FileWriter("file.txt", true)` the second parameter tells taht the data shouldnot be truncated on open, the new content is appended. But in your case you should open the file before the loop and close it once you are done after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use many different streams to write to file.

I personally like to work with `PrintWriter` [here](http://www.google.com/url?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)
You can flag to append in the FileWriter (the true in the following example):

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", true)));
    out.println(sw.toString());
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) ?

Open it before you loop and generate your required output. As you write to the FileWriter it'll append to the buffer and write out your accumulated output upon a `close()`

Note that you can open a FileWriter in *overwrite* or *append* mode, so you can append to existing files.

Here's [a simple tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/filewriter.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Apache commons IO :

```
FileUtils.write(new File("file.txt"), sw.toString(), /*append:*/ true);
```